# How to set just one default argument pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a function :

```
void my_functions(int a, int b = 42);
```

And I want to bind it using only the default argument for `b`:

```
 m.def("my_functions", &my_functions, pb::arg("b") = 42); // just default for b
```

This doesn't work, I get:

```
/cache/venv/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:219:40: error: static assertion failed: The number of argument annotations does not match the number of function arguments
  219 |             expected_num_args<Extra...>(
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
  220 |                 sizeof...(Args), cast_in::args_pos >= 0, cast_in::has_kwargs),
```

What's the right way of doing it?

Comment: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#default-arguments

Comment: Have you tried `m.def("my_functions", &my_functions, pb::arg("a"), pb::arg("b") = 42);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how:

```
m.def("my_functions", &my_functions, pb::arg(), pb::arg("b") = 42)
```

See here: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html#non-converting-arguments

> When specifying `py::arg` options it is necessary to provide the same
> number of options as the bound function has arguments. …

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to specify names for all arguments in pybind11 if named arguments are desired.  See https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#default-arguments