# Pybind11 default values for Custom type casters

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, default-arguments

I have a function :

```
void my_functions(int a, some_type b);
```

And I want to bind it using only the default argument for `b`:

```
 m.def("my_functions", &my_functions,  pb::arg("a"),  pb::arg("b") = function_that_returns_my_type()); // just default for b
```

What's different from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75890415/11261546) is that some_type has an automatic custom type caster declared in `PYBIND11_NAMESPACE`

This compiles, but when I call in python

```
my_functions(5)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: my_functions(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (a: int, b: some_type = python_object_custom_casted)
```